# Wordpress Contact From7 selected current day by default

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am new to WordPress and contact form 7. Is there any possibility to get today's date in the contact form 7 datepicker to be selected by default? I have this short-code is `[date* all-date id:date-field min:today ]`. It didn't work for me. This is what see the user when open the form.
[image]

i want to be like this :

[image]

i try this, but not help me

```
var date = new Date();
$("#date-field").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'd-M-y'
}).datepicker('setDate', date);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
   var now = new Date(); 
   var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
   var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
  $('#date-field').val(today);
$("#date-field").attr("min", today);
```

for me is working ....